# MySQL Foreach row in table

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have two tables: `posts` and `tags`. And I want to, via pure SQL, iterate through all `posts` with the `posts.type` set to `user`. With those `post.id` of those matched posts, I need co create a new `tags` with the given `post.key` for that row.

```
posts Table:
id
type

tags
id
post_key
name
```

So something like this (pseudo code):

```
FOREACH(SELECT post.id FROM posts WHERE post.type = 'user')
  INSERT INTO tags (post_key, name) VALUES (post.id, 'mytag')
```

Is this doable with SQL alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You can simply use an insert with a select statement from the other table.  It is not the same logically as iterating over each row, but will get the same results (and perform much better)

Try:

```
INSERT INTO tags (post_key, name)
  SELECT post.id, 'mytag' 
  FROM posts
  WHERE post.type = 'user'
```

Comment: *palmfacemoment nice lol.. the foreach through me off, but this is the general solution. +1